# Notepad++ Replace new line inside text

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have this sample, because is one of one million rows with that.
I have this text:

```
<tr class="even">
<td><a href="http://www.ujk.edu.pl/">Jan Kochanowski 
University of Humanities and Sciences (Swietokrzyska Pedagogical 
University) / Uniwersytet Humanistyczno Przyrodniczy Jana Kochanowskiego
w Kielcach</a></td>
```

I want to replace to be like that:

```
<tr class="even">
<td><a href="http://www.ujk.edu.pl/">Jan Kochanowski University of Humanities and Sciences (Swietokrzyska Pedagogical University) / Uniwersytet Humanistyczno Przyrodniczy Jana Kochanowskiegow Kielcach</a></td>
```

I tried that REGEX: (.*)
But didn't work.

Comment: Using textpad (press F8 for find and replace with the "regular expression" option checked) and simply replacing `\n` with a single space - worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work like that, because if I relace all \n, I will get just one line html.

Comment: The do two replaces, the second will replace `<td>` with `\n<td>` ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the replace window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Then enter

- Find what: `([^>])[\r\n]{1,2}`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Check `Regular Expression`

---

- `[^>]` matches a character that isn't a `>`
- The `{1,2}` protects against a file that may only have a newline and not a carriage return.
- `\1` replaces just the character that was in the grouping `( )`.

Comment: Are you not able to upgrade to v. 6.1.3?

Comment: Trying use \ instead of $.  I've updated my solution.  Both methods work in v 6.1.3 and I know the \ works back to version v4.9

Comment: What to you have selected for Search Mode?

Comment: @alfasin Sorry, I got you confused with the OP, but I can confirm this regex works in Windows with Notepad++ v. 6.1.3.  It works if the line ends with \r\n or just \n.

Comment: @alfasin Not sure what problem you have, but the regex is working fine. Unless you have some other file in your notepad++ or you missed something with "Direction" or the regular expression option. You could try selecting the whole text, check "In selection" and click the corresponding Replace All.

Answer (score 3):

Open Notepad++
Click Search >> Replace..

Replace with: \n

At the bottom you will find "Search Mode", click "Extended"

Live example here: http://postimg.org/image/c66pw8kkr/

Answer (score 2):

If you can't make jmstoker's solution work, try like this:

- you need to check if the line breaks are just `CRLF` or just one of them, for that, click on the toolbar the icon "show all characters" or go to menu View -> Show Symbol -> Show all characters
- in the replace dialog select the "Extended" search mode
- in the "find what:" field, write this: `\r\n` (or just `\r` or just `\n`, basically match `CR` with `\r` and `LF` with `\n`)
- leave the replace with field empty
- once this is done, all the line breaks will have been replaced, but you want the `<tr class="even">` to be on its own line, so just replace still using an extended search `<tr class="even"><td>` with `<tr class="even">\r\n<td>`

I'm guessing you also have rows with class "odd" or something like that so you might need to repeat that last step with the different class :)

Comment: Doesn't work like that, because if I relace all \n, I will get just one line html.

Comment: if you took the time to read my complete answer you would see that the last step takes care of putting the <tr> back in its own line..