# Regular expression help: search character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following code for example:

```
SELECT Something, ?, Count('Something2') AS Total FROM table WHERE Id=? AND Time>NOW() FOR UPDATE
```

Now I need to search for the `?` between `SELECT` and `FROM`. How can I do that? Something like `SELECT \? FROM`

Comment: What do you mean "need to search" ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I need to search for the '?' character within Notepad++

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do? Do you want a regular expression? To determine whether there is a question mark anywhere between select and from? Or what?

Comment: If you just need to search for a literal ?, then press ctrl-f, put "search mode" to "normal", and type a ? into the box. If you want to do it with search mode still as "regular expression", then type `\?` into the search box. If you want to search for the entire string from Select to From, then use `SELECT.*?\?.*?FROM`.

Comment: did you try anything? `?` seems like an obvious thing to try, with `\?` being the next, and correct, one.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I only want to search for the ? character between SELECT and FROM, so the character after 'Id' should not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookahead to match only the "?"

```
(\?)(?=.*FROM.*)
```

make sure to use case-insensitive so you won't miss queries in which `from` is written in lower-case.

Most of the regex flavors don't support lookbehind with unfixed size - which is why you can't use the SELECT in the regex.

Comment: Thanks, this regular expression works with PHP, but not with the Notepad++ search function. How to solve that?

Comment: @Jordy weird but I had the same issue yesterday (with Notepad++): http://stackoverflow.com/a/18861906/1057429 didn't get a chance to check it on another computer though...

Comment: Strange, I updated Notepad++ to the latest version and it works now... Thanks!